# Creating jenkins pipelines in loop over DSL

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, dsl, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

In my case, I'm creating in a loop similar pipelines which differ in variables. eg:

```
prefix = "prefix"
def repos = ['repo1', 'repo2', 'repo3', 'repo4']
for(repo in repos) {

pipelineJob(prefix + "-" + repo) {
        definition {
                cps {
script("""
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage("first") {
            steps {
                println "${repo}"
            }
        }
    }
}
""".stripIndent())                 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Everything is fine when the body of pipelines are the same but sometimes I want to change one little thing which could be handled by if statement but in the script body it is impossible. For example:

```
prefix = "prefix"
def repos = ['repo1', 'repo2', 'repo3', 'repo4']
for(repo in repos) {

pipelineJob(prefix + "-" + repo) {
        definition {
                cps {
script("""
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage("first") {
            steps {
                println "${repo}"
            }
        }
""".stripIndent()) 
    if (repo == 'repo1') {
script("""      
        stage("stage only for repo1") {
            steps {
                repo1 only
            }
        }
    }
}
""".stripIndent())
    } else {
script("""      
        stage("stage for other repos") {
            steps {
                other repo
            }
        }
    }
}
""".stripIndent())
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

In this case, the beginning of pipelines is replaced by the second script clause so pipeline bodies are incomplete. My first question sounds: Can I combine that scripts definitions? I was trying to combine by "+" operator but it doesn't work.
I also was trying to create DSL pipelines by `script(readFileFromWorkspace('project-a-workflow.groovy'))` instead of a raw script definition but it doesn't work with variables.

My second question is: how is the best approach to managing Jenkins pipelines in DSL with use case similar to my - creating similar pipelines in a loop with handling variables. Because pasting raw pipeline definitions are very ugly especially that we have to escape every Jenkins pipeline variable.